# LEGO Event in Fountain Hills Arizona

Tags: lego-group

I'm trying to find documentation for a special event that Lego did in Fountain Hills Arizona. I believe it was in the time of LEGO Power Miners and the castle series.

They had a tent set up and had 4 different events. One was building a LEGO tower in a time set, another was just looking at a big set up (of what I think was a giant Power Miners MOC). You would get stickers for each thing completed. You would have a lanyard with a yellow 2 by 2 LEGO brick, with the studs being where you put the sticker for each event.

I can't seem to find documentation on this, so would anyone else out there know this or a similar event that happened, and if there is any info about it out there?